# Add new select then add selection to array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to add two new select boxes (from and until) using ng-click and then add then update the users selection in my scope. I can add the select boxes but I'm having trouble binding the selects to my array.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="time in availability.times" class="calendar--availability--time">
    <select ng-model="availability.times.time.from[$index]">
     <option>...</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="availability.times.time.to[$index]">
     <option>...</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button class="button--secondary margin__top" ng-click="addNewTime()"><span>Add another slot</span></button>
```

My js/angular:

```
$scope.availability = {
    times: [
        time: {from: '09:00', to: '21:00'}
    ]
}

$scope.addNewTime = function() {

    var newTime = {time: { from: '', until: ''}};
    $scope.availability.times.push(newTime);

}
```

Comment: just create directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues in both your HTML markup and your JavaScript code.

The `time` name does not belong inside the array brackets. You don't really seem to need the `time` name, just `from` and `to`. So this:

```
times: [
    time: {from: '09:00', to: '21:00'}
]
```

Should be this:

```
times: [
    {from: '09:00', to: '21:00'}
]
```

Then you need to reflect this in your `addNewTime` function and also correct the typo. Where you have:

```
var newTime = {time: { from: '', until: ''}};
```

It should be:

```
var newTime = {from: '', to: ''};
```

(Note that you had `until` instead of `to`).

For the `ng-model` binding in your HTML, there is no need to reference the full model with the `$index` variable. You just need the `time` variable that is created by `ng-repeat`. So instead of this:

```
<select ng-model="availability.times.time.from[$index]">
```

You should have this:

```
<select ng-model="time.from">
```

Here is a fiddle that shows it all working: http://jsfiddle.net/etnfwdw7/.

Finally, you should familiarize yourself with the developer tools built into most browsers. Some of these errors would have shown up in the developer console.